# what's wrong in this factorial function (from book : programming in scala)?

Tags: scala, factorial

here is the factorial function found in Programming in Scala Book :

```
// factorial function
def factorial(x: BigInteger): BigInteger =
  if (x==BigInteger.ZERO) 
    BigInteger.ONE 
  else 
    x.multiply(factorial(x.subtract(BigInteger.ONE)))
```

i call it from my main function :

```
// using factorial function
factorial(8)
```

in scala IDE, i got "type mismatch" error...

Could you tell me what's wrong in these lines ?

Thanks for your help :-)

Comment: You are using an `int` and the function requires a `BigDecimal`.

Comment: Use the Constructor of BigInteger (with a string) or the valueOf function (with a long).

Comment: There seems to be an implicit conversion from `int` to `BigDecimal` in the [BigDecimal class](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.math.BigDecimal$) - which `BigDecimal` are you importing?

Comment: thanks guys, i'm learning Scala and try the exemples provided in the book Programming in Scala.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You had better use `BigInt`.
Do not use `BigInteger`.
I know why you used `BigInteger` is that there is an example in the book using `BigInteger`, anyway.

`BigInt` and `BigDecimal` (in scala.math package) are for Scala.
`BigInteger` and `BigDecimal` (in java.math package) are for Java.
Scala also can use `BigInteger` and `java.math.BigDecimal`, but they are not optimized for Scala. Implicit conversions may not work for them. (For example, `Int` to `BigInteger` is not automatically processed)

If you want to use `BigInteger` anyway,
you can call the function by

```
factorial(BigInteger.valueOf(8)) // Long to java.math.BigInteger
```

or

```
factorial(new BigInteger("8")) // String to java.math.BigInteger
```

---

However, if you use `BigInt` of Scala, the code gets much simpler.

```
// factorial function
def factorial(x: BigInt): BigInt =
  if (x == 0) 
    1
  else 
    x * factorial(x - 1)
```

```
// using factorial function
factorial(8)
```

Since `x` or return type of `factorial()` is already `BigInt`, multiplication with `x` or `factorial()` results in `BigInt` not `Int`, which prevents overflow. `BigInt` also supports operator overloading (in this case operator * and -), which is not in Java.

---

Also, you can define an even simpler factorial function in Scala.

```
def factorial(x: BigInt): BigInt = (BigInt(1) to x).product
```

Comment: thanks Naetmul for these explanation that help me to understand and solve my problem ;-)